# Why is my Hibernate DAO behaving differently after upgrading to 5?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an old project that ran on 3.6. I have just updated to Hibernate 5 and i have a couple of tests that don't run anymore.

case in point:

```
@Test
public void testConflictingKeyword() {

    Location loc = locationDao.findByKeyword("l1");

    try {
        loc.setKeyword("l2");
        locationDao.update(loc);
        fail("should not be able to update entity, another entity with keyword exists");
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

This test runs fine on 3.6. I can see that the dao update is called, and that i get a constrantviolationexception.

However, after upgrading to 5, the update method is just not called anymore.

However if i add another `locationDao.findByKeyword("l1")` method call after the update, then the update sql is executed!

I suspect it has something to do with autocommits and flushing, but i am not sure where to look and make 5 behave as it did in 3.6...

If someone has some clues to share, i'd be grateful.

Comment: do you call flush() inside your update methods?

Comment: No i don't. it has always worked, so i havent seen any need.

Comment: Can you test it with hibernate 4? Just to figure out where they changed something regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Once again: this is problem with flush mode.

By default hibernate is using AUTO flush mode, which tells that system might call flush sometimes to ensure that no stale states are returned.

while you were on 3.6 your session was flushing automatically every time during update calls. (why store unmodified state, if user is calling update: make that happen, and be complient with AUTO mode by default).

Now 5 is trying to improve application performance and cut off numbers of database server interaction. and thus is not flushing during each update/create call. however when you try to execute the query for objects of specific type, it checks the state of the session, and sees that there are modification to objects of queried type, and thus performs a flush before exact SELECT.

In order to overcome this: call flushes manually when you expect that. As I can assume, you are relying on database unique check in mentioned test, and verification happens only during flush.  This will be the easiest way of modification.   Another approach would be to extract unique check for pure database to service-based...

Or simply change the hibernate configuration to use FlushMode.ALWAYS.

Comment: I think you are right, but didn't quite get the part about 3.6: "why store unmodified state, if user is calling update: make that happen, and be complient with AUTO mode by default".. Can you pls elaborate, or point to the docs?

Comment: Hey, thanks for great input. I don't get one thing - i do not, and never have, configured FlushMode myself. Does that mean that in 3.6 the default flushmode was NOT Auto? Do you know of anything documenting this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they changed the behavior of AUTO Flushmode in Hibernate 5.2. I could only find a [private blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-jpa-and-hibernate-define-the-auto-flush-mode/) in the short time.

> Since Hibernate 5.2, if you bootstrap Hibernate using JPA (e.g.
>   persistence.xml), then even the Hibernate FlushType.AUTO will behave
>   just like its JPA counterpart. Only if you bootstrap Hibernate using
>   the native mechanism, will the Hibernate Session use the legacy
>   FlushType.AUTO behavior.

Cheers, Rainer